# How To Use Cloud Init To mount an unformatted EBS volume

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init, amazon-linux

## Context

I am using the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin for jenkins which allows me to dynamically provision new cloud instances as build slaves in AWS EC2.

I am launching `ami-d834aba1` (Amazon Linux 2017.09.1).

The plugin supports providing user-data and block device mapping too, currently I provide config like this after reading https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

### User Data

```
#cloud-config
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all
package_upgrade: true

bootcmd:
 - [ cloud-init-per, once, mkfs, -t, ext4, /dev/nvme1n1 ]

fs_setup:
 - cmd: mkfs -t %(filesystem)s -L %(label)s %(device)s
   label: jenkins
   filesystem: 'ext4'
   overwrite: false
   device: '/dev/nvme1n1'

mounts:
 - [ /dev/nvme1n1, /jenkins, "ext4", "defaults,nofail", "0", "2" ]

users:
 - default
 - name: jenkins
   homedir: /jenkins
   lock_passwd: true
   ssh_authorized_keys:
     - a-key
```

### Block Device Mapping

```
/dev/sdd=:100:true:gp2::encrypted
```

## Desired Behaviour

The instance would launch and would attach a new 100GB encrypted EBS volume which would be formatted as `ext4` and mounted at `/jenkins` as the home directory of the jenkins user.

## Observed Behaviour

The instance launches, the 100GB encrypted EBS volume is created and attached to the EC2 instance (shows as in use and attached in AWS console). However,

1) `df -h` doesn't show the filesystem.

2)
    `cat /etc/fstab
    /dev/nvme1n1    /jenkins    ext4    defaults,nofail,comment=cloudconfig 0   2` does show it

3) `sudo file -s /dev/nvme1n1
/dev/nvme1n1: data` shows the volume as `data` formatted rather than `ext4`

4) sudo mount-a fails due to the filesystem not being ext4.

## Manual Hack

If i manually SSH to the machine after boot and run:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Creating filesystem with 26214400 4k blocks and 6553600 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 7a434f7a-c048-4c3d-8098-b810e2ff8f84
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Then  `sudo mount -a` it seems to mount the volume.

## Questions

Is there any way to have the device formatted and mounted automatically? I tried with and without the

`bootcmd:
     - [ cloud-init-per, once, mkfs, -t, ext4, /dev/nvme1n1 ]`

Ideally it'd happen all before the user gets created since the home directory of the new user is going to be on this new mount.

If the instance is stopped and started/restarted I'd not want to ideally lose all data by the reformatting happening again on boot.

Comment: I'd wager this is off-topic and better fit on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: *"`/dev/nvme1n1: data` shows the volume as data formatted rather than ext4"*  The volume is not formatted as anything.  Because the disk is encrypted, but unused, it looks like random noise, so the `file` utility categorizes it with the generic label "data."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

cloud-init on Amazon Linux does **not** support the `fs_setup` module. Hence, your disk is not formatted.  Furthermore the home directory /jenkins is created for the user, and used as a mount point. This hides the home directory.

I would suggest:

```
bootcmd:
 - test -z "$(blkid /dev/nvme1n1)" && mkfs -t ext4 -L jenkins /dev/nvme1n1
 - mkdir -p /jenkins

mounts:
 - [ "/dev/nvme1n1", "/jenkins", "ext4", "defaults,nofail", "0", "2" ]

runcmd:
 - useradd -m -b /jenkins jenkins
```

Comment: Are you sure you can reliably determine the disk as `nvme1n1` it seems of late that even a simple root ebs volume + ebs volume setup. can be named in any order i.e. root disk as `nvme1n1` and your additional disk as `nvme0n1`

Comment: Indeed with the NVMe based instance types, the nvme device name may change on boot. Best is to use readlink on the logical device name. I have explained it in more detail in my blog https://binx.io/blog/2019/01/26/how-to-mount-an-ebs-volume-on-nvme-based-instance-types/

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that with user data script when launching EC2 instance. Here's an example user script:

```sh
# make a directory for a drive
sudo mkdir /data

# format disk
yes | sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb

# mount it
sudo mount /dev/sdb /data

# persist
uuid=$(sudo blkid /dev/sdb | sed -n 's/.*UUID=\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/p')
sudo bash -c "echo 'UUID=${uuid}     /data       ext4   defaults' >> /etc/fstab"
```

Comment: i like your answer. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to obtain the `uuid` without piping to `sed` Do you know an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work out how to achieve this using the default AMI and a cloud init script.

I have solved this by creating my own AMI based on the AMI I wanted that has an encrypted EBS volume.. Now I just launch this AMI by ID and don't worry about formatting EBS, attaching, mounting etc.

It's more simple, requires less config. However, the big downside is when a new base AMI comes out I can't just simply update the AMI ID to latest. I need to create a new base AMI of my own.

Not ideal, but it works. If anyone knows how to do this "properly" I'd like to hear more about it.

Answer (score 1):

The magical `x-systemd.makefs` fstab option can be used in cloud-init. Then the systemd mount unit will automatically format to the specified filesystem (don't use `auto`) before mounting, if the device has no filesystem yet.

Note: manually mounting with `mount` won't trigger formatting, but starting via systemd, either directly (`systemctl start mnt-foo.mount`), or by a unit dependency (see `RequiresMountsFor` in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) works.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html.

Comment: Note for other people trying this on EC2:  check your version of `systemd` and `cloud-init` before trying any of the fstab magical options.  They work great **if** you have sufficiently recent versions of the software, but a lot of AWS' default AMIs have much older versions for stability, with package repository settings meant to keep them that way (for good reasons).  Tread with care!

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner way to obtain the `uuid` without piping to `sed`.

```
blkid /dev/sdxx -S UUID -o value
```

Comment: It should be a lowercase `-s` (`-s, --match-tag tag`). `-S` is an option for a different purpose.